# sql nested statement is extremely slow compared to hardcoded values with same results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sorry I can't post the actual views in question here, suffice to say there are 25 joins and about 200 fields - it's hideous - but I'm hoping an example of how the view is called might be enough for someone to shed some light on an issue I have.

If I run this statement:

```
select top 100 personId 
from vw_GetPeople 
where personFirstname = 'John'
```

I get a list of 100 id's in less than a second.

If I then hardcode those 100 id's into a statement like this

```
select * 
from vw_AllPersonAssociatedGarbage 
where personId in ( <<my 100 comma-separated id's here>> )
```

Then the view returns results in a few seconds.

If I nest the first statement to try and use it like this:

```
select * 
from vw_AllPersonAssociatedGarbage 
where personId in (select top 100 personId from vw_GetPeople 
                   where personFirstname = 'John')
```

then the statement takes about a minute to complete.

Why is the nested statement not simply equivalent to the "harcoded" personId list statement?

Comment: `TOP 100` (without an `ORDER BY`) and a `WHERE` to limit the values are *completely* different. The first just tells the instance to return 100 arbitrary rows; what ever rows it finds "first" perhaps. For the later, the RDBMS will need to perform a a seek (or scan if you're lacking indexes) and then return the relevant rows. Considering the time it takes, I would suggest it's performing a scan, due to not having any indexes. Also the first query just returns `personId`, and the latter *all* the columns, which doesn't make the the queries comparible either.

Comment: From the looks of it is that you may have missing indexex. But the only way to tell is if you post the Execution Plans. The query `where personId in
    ( <<my 100 id's with comma separation here>> )` maybe using the Clustered Index already available by default on most tables for the search that is why it is fast.

Comment: Because the subquery and the view are combined into one new execution plan that happens to be much worse. Normally this is to your benefit, in this case it happens to not be.

Comment: Because the queries aren't the same and don't have the same execution plans. If you inspect the execution plans you'll see the difference. You haven't posted the views' code so it's impossible to guess what the actual queries are. Most likely there are missing indexes or bad statistics. The inner query produces "random" results too, as there's no `ORDER BY` clause. All these may force the server to use an inefficient plan, eg executing the inner query for every outer record.

Comment: Without knowing much about your database, table and indexes it's har to be specific.
But the "top 100" select just reads the first 100 it finds where name is john. Lets say there are 1 million rows, then perhaps it has to read 10.000 rows to find 100 people named John.
The last selects reads these 10.000 rows, but then - if ther is no index on personid - it has to read ALL 1.000.000 rows to find the rows mathcing the person id's

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the comments, makes a lot of sense. I looked at the execution plan for the monster view (with all the assoc. garbage) and it had so many nodes I didn't even know where to begin. I actually think for my use case it'll be much easier to build a two-query statement to first find the top 100 named 'John' then explicitly search for their id's on the 2nd view as a quick fix. It gives the "same" results as in anything that fits the criteria 'John' just executes completely differently.

Comment: You could try adding an `ORDER BY` to the inner query, or you could write the inner query's data to a temporary table (with indexes) and join with it. That's what the server would do if it knew the inner query was so expensive

Comment: If you wanted to display the data for 100 customers at a time, you'd need the ORDER BY and the temp table anyway, to produce consistent results *and* avoid executing the expensive query each time you wanted to get the next 100 IDs

Comment: I tried adding an ORDER BY to the nested statement and gave up after it hit 30 seconds. Even though the separate statement with order by took less than 2. Honestly I'd love to post the views because they are an absolute HOOT but they're a bit sensitive.

Comment: But thanks definitely @PanagiotisKanavos I will include the `order by` to make sure the results are the latest top 100 by date anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 100 personId from vw_GetPeople where personFirstname = 'John'
```

Returns in seconds yes?
Try inserting that result set into a temp table or table variable and place the temp table in the subquery. The temp table or table variable will be smaller than your view.

```
select * from vw_AllPersonAssociatedGarbage where personId in
    ( SELECT personID FROM #persons )

select * from vw_AllPersonAssociatedGarbage where personId in
    ( SELECT personID FROM @persons )
```

It's most likely re-running that select top 100 for every record in vw_AllPersonAssociatedGarbage which can be costly if there is a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the nested statement not simply equivalent to the "harcoded" personId list statement?

In SQL Server, views are basically inserted into the query as code and then compiled in the context of the entire statement.  That means that the execution plan for the view might vary depending on how it is used.  This is probably the phenomenon that you are seeing, but it is unclear whether one or both views are affected.

You can try using a `join` instead:

```
select apag.* 
from vw_AllPersonAssociatedGarbage apag join
     (select top 100 personId
      from vw_GetPeople 
      where personFirstname = 'John'
     ) p
     on p.personId = apag.personId;
```

`IN` is actually a more complicated operation because `join` can return duplicate rows.

If all else fails, you can use a temporary table or table variable for views.  However, if the views are widely-used, you might really want an *indexed view*, which materializes the underlying data and should benefit all queries.